# How does a double axis movement system work?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I don't know what the right term for the machine is, but I would like to look into machines that can move something with two bars. For example, the machine that moves the basketball hoop in Stuff Made Here's never-miss basketball hoop. Does anyone know what this is actually called and how I might start to build one that can move, say, six inches in any direction?

Comment: Are you talking about moving something along an "x" axis and a "y" axis? Usually done with leadscrews or other actuators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall "study" of such movement, particularly with regard to the math, mechanics and operation/programming is called kinematics. You'll find references to x-y or cartesian kinematics and in the 3D printer world, delta kinematics. There's a few other unusual implementations such as the hang printer, a few arm printer designs with one using polar kinematics.

For light, fast x/y movement, consider to check out [coreXY](http://corexy.com/) studies/constructions. The stepper motors are fixed to a frame, with the belts running through a series of pulleys to create carriage movement.

Comment: I'll look at it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Such systems are called Gantry systems. If it is two axis, say X and Y, then it is called and X-Y Gantry system.